# Проблема с расположением рядов в InlineKeyboardMarkup

Tags: python, aiogram

Как мне сделать так, чтоб кнопка `Копировать` была одна, а `Назад` и `Меню` вместе в один ряд?

```
inline_buttons = [
    ("Копировать", "copy"),
    ("Назад", "back"),
    ("Меню", "menu")
]
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for inline_button, inline_button_cd in inline_buttons:
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(inline_button, callback_data=f"prefix:{inline_button_cd}"))
await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```py
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Копировать", callback_data=f"prefix:copy"))
markup.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data=f"prefix:back"),
    InlineKeyboardButton("Меню", callback_data=f"prefix:menu"))
```